# Matlab how to autocomplete parentheses in my command window in 2021a

Tags: matlab

I found the option in autocoding section that I can turn on autocompletion for live editor and app designer. And it does work fine in my live editor. However, when I am coding in my command window, the parentheses won't autocomplete. Same for my quotations.

Wonder if anyone can help me with this issue. It was not really answered in matlab forum.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autocoding options are only applicable to the Live Editor and App Designer windows. These options are not currently available in the Command or Editor windows.